# Swift: Adding array values to in-app email message body

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have some values in an array and want to add them to the in-app email message body.
I tried running a for loop and adding all the array values to the message body but unfortunately only the last value in array is getting displayed.
Something like this..

```
for(var i=0; i < userDataName.count; i++)
    {
        mc.setMessageBody("\(userDataName[i]) - \(userDataStatus[i])", isHTML: false)
    }
```

I know it's dumb but couldn't find any better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that `setMessageBody` appends (nor its name indicates that), so I think you should construct the body first, using a string variable, and then set the body at the end of the loop:

```
var body = ""
for(var i=0; i < userDataName.count; i++)
{
    body += "\(userDataName[i]) - \(userDataStatus[i])\n"
}
mc.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)
```

or even:

```
var body = (0..<userDataName.count)
    .map { index in "\(userDataName[index]) - \(userDataStatus[index])" }
    .reduce("") { $0 + $1 + "\n"}

mc.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)
```